# How to determine the relations between races?

Tags: dawn-of-worlds

I am thinking of playing a game called Dawn Of Worlds but i can't find something that allows people to decide which races go to war or which races trade with eachother. Are there any supplements that can be used to determine such things or is it left to player initiative?

Answer (score 1):

In Dawn of Worlds the relations between races grow out of their cultures and alignments. The cultures are created by the player who created the race; the alignments can be changed with the Purify and Corrupt actions.